# c++ crtp for adapter: pass threw temporary return value

Tags: c++, adapter, crtp

The following simple code snipped does not compile with the following compiler message:

```
binding reference of type 'int' to value of type 'const int' drops 'const' qualifier
        > return m;
```

Code Snippet:

```
class Base {
    public:
    int& ref() const {
        return m;
    }

    private:
    int m = 0;
};

template <typename Base>
class Final {
    public:
    int& ref() const {
        return b.ref();
    }

    private:
    Base b;
};
```

I do believe that's because the return value of Base::ref in the Final class instantiation is a temporary reference and thus implicit casted to a const int reference.
But how would I pass threw the return type of the Base implementation without const casting.
Is a temporary object needed for every passthrew if multiple adapters like this one are in use?

PS: I know that one should not return references to member variables. This is just a simple example. The actual pattern is used for Iterator Adapters.

Comment: ref() is const, meaning you can only return a const reference, and not a reference, a temporary doesn't change that.

Comment: I'd say that is the `const` qualified `ref()` in `Base` that makes the compiler complain. It's not a temporary reference. It's a reference to the `m` in `Base`, which is `const` inside `ref()` since you made `ref() const`.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not CRTP that uses heritage (and not composition). Independently the origin of your error is that your **const** method returns a **mutable** reference

Comment: I suspect that you are misunderstanding the reason for this error, and asking for details about this misunderstanding.  Because you made `Base::ref()` const, `Base` is const in that context.  Which makes `Base::m` const.  You can not implicity create an `int&` from a `const int`.

Comment: I got my mistake - thanks everyone :)